# Editing JTable Values Programmatically

Tags: java, swing, ide, lua, jtable

I'm currently working on a sort-of IDE for Lua, and I'm currently making the New Project wizard.

Once the user has input the project details, I'd like them to be shown to the user as a confirmation. This information should be displayed in a JTable, to make the UI cleaner.

Project Details:
[image]

Detail Confirmation:
[image]

I'm still working on the UI, but I'd like to have this stuff finished, before I start working on the actual syntax-highlighting and the editor in general.

At the moment, this is the code I'm trying to get to work (and failing miserably):

```
if (jTabbedPane2.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        jLabel2.setIcon(_wizard3);
        // Enter values into table
        jTable1.setValueAt(jTextField1.getText(), 1, 1);
        jTabbedPane2.setSelectedIndex(2);
        return;
    }
```

How can I edit the table contents using this or similar code?

Comment: `and failing miserably` - also failing to ask a question. I have no idea what the code fragment represents. The simple answer to your question heading is, yes you would use the setValueAt(...) method to update the TableModel programmatically.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry. I was kind of in a hurry.

Comment: Is your EDIT an answer? if so, you should post an answer to your own question to keep clear separation between question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by OP:

I had a look in the constructor and after a few minutes of searching, I found what i was looking for.
Just in case anybody else needs this:

```
// Set the new model
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            // This is where your (new) values go.
            {jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText()}
        },
        new String [] {
            // These are the headers for each column.
            "Project Language", "Project Type"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            // Set these for each column. 
            // If false, the end-user cannot edit the contents
            // If true, the end-user is free to play with the data inside.
            false, false
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
```